# Putting on hold - a bit hasty?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I posted a riddle.  [I'm slower than a sloth [on hold]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18683/im-slower-than-a-sloth)

Within 2 minutes (literally) it was put on hold.

I feel it would have been politer to make a comment first rather than putting it on hold.

I edited immediately.

Now it's just stuck in limbo. There is no option for anyone to vote it open. I can't contact the person to say I've fixed it. What now?

Comment: (Apparently you can comment on posts put on hold. TIL) To discuss further actions, you can always head over to chat (which is accessible from the Meta sidebar) and ping the person who closed your puzzle, by typing @ followed by their name. The mods here are always happy to explain their actions, especially to newcomers who might not be familiar with the rules/guidelines of Puzzling!

Comment: @BaileyM Comments aren't locked unless it's *deleted*.

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day! Either way, chat is not a bad way to try to get the attention of someone you want an answer from, since it's instant. :)

Comment: Clearly, close voters wished to demonstrate that they were not the proper answer to your puzzle.

Comment: Your last paragraph isn't actually right. People with enough rep (over 1000?) *can* cast reopen votes - in fact your post automatically appeared in the Reopen Votes review queue since it was edited after it was closed - and anybody *can* (using "@Emrakul") contact the person who closed it in the comments on your post. In fact I'd already done both of these by the time I saw this meta post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason to put it on hold fast is to keep answers from coming in before it's right. Edits that invalidate answers after the fact aren't good for anyone. If it needs to be put on hold, putting it on hold *fast* is good.

As far as reopening goes, it automatically enters a review queue when you edit it (after being put on hold). People with the reopen privilege will be able to see it there and vote, along with those that see it on the front page, where it's very visible right now.

Comment: Okay - I didn't know that. I'll accept this answer as soon as I am able.